# Turn off logging for ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner

Tags: java, mybatis, c3p0

How to turn off logging messages from ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner in mybatis + C3P0 java application?

In my Java application i'm frequently getting logs like

"ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:236 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner@721a23f8: Adding task to queue -- com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@43adfff8"

from C3P0. Can anyone please suggest how can we stop it?

Comment: We'd need to know which framework you use for logging. But usually, you can set the log level for this class to something like `ERROR` to prevent info/debug messages to show

Comment: You can make changes in `c3p0-config.xml` for more see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging

Comment: I'm using log4j for logging